# Не работает локализация файлов сообщений в Django

Tags: django, django-admin, locale

На продакшн-сервере (nginx+uWSGI) имеется проект на Django 1.9 и Python 2.7.

Необходимо перевести сообщения в формах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал в корне проекта (и в приложении) директорию **locale**, затем делаю следующее:

```
django-admin makemessages -l ru -e html,txt
django-admin -d djangojs
django-admin compilemessages
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В **settings.py** прописал:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
LOCALE_PATHS = [
        PROJECT_ROOT + 'locale',
    ]
```

Может кто подскажет в чём подвох?

Comment: это случаем не стандартная валидация браузера?( очень похоже на ошибку в фф )